# How do I get rid of this Gradle error?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.
Searched in the following locations:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.jar 
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle /4.1/gradle-4.1.pom


 https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
4.1/gradle-4.1.jar
https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.pom
https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.jar
Required by:
project :
Open File
```

I downloaded the source code of an app and when I try to run I get all kinds of gradle errors. I have been trying to solve it since two days but so far I have been unable to do so. I updated Android Studio to 3.1 but the error is still there.  Nothing works.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. I deleted all the gradle version in the 'dist' folder and let
   Android Studio download everything again.
2. I have tried to enable
       'offline mode' in the Gradle build settings in Android Studio.
3. I also enabled 'use local gradle distribution'.

P.S: Creating a new project works fine. I just need to run this specific project.

Comment: add this to your gradle `runtime group: 'org.gradle', name: 'gradle-wrapper', version: '4.1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gragle version declared is 4.1, but since you are using Android Studio 3.1, the gradle version should be declared as follow into your application `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        ...
    }
}
```

You can find the link between the gradle plugin version and the actual gradle version [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle)